# How to close all opened windows from python?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I am making a personal voice assistant in python. And in my program I wrote a function which can shutdown my pc. But I also want to close all opened window before shutting down. So is there any python script to do that or any windows shortcut key?

Comment: Try `taskkill /im explorer.exe -f` and then `explorer`

Comment: That mean i have to write {taskkill /im explorer.exe -f} in cmd? @sa_n__u

Comment: It's alright. And no, not CMD, look at `subprocess` module documentation

Comment: Ok ! thank you for your suggestion @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `powershell` or `DOS shutdown` script using subprocess:

```py
import subprocess

# forced shutdown closes windows without saving; you might need to add shell=True 

COMMAND = "Stop-Computer -Force"
subprocess.run(['powershell', '-command', COMMAND], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

We can also close windows and then shutdown

```py
# replace command above with below
COMMAND  = """(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\"} | stop-process; Stop-Computer"""
```

DOS

```
# from shutdown documentation 
# /s  Shuts down the computer
# /f   Forces running applications to close without warning users.
# /t <xxx> Sets the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.

subprocess.run(['shutdown', '/s', '/t 0', '/f'], shell=False)
```

Comment: And if I only want to close my all opened window then what should I do? @Prayson W. Daniel